# How to prevent style duplication in Rails HTML emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am trying to build rails HTML emails, but the structure (header and footer) of the emails is duplicated in each one. Typically it's not a problem, but with the inline styles as well, it seems like it can be an issue if I want to change the color. How can I pull these elements out of each file and into one?

Also, is there anyway to eliminate the duplication of text between the html.erb and text.erb files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple way to do it is to reference a couple of partials. Let's say they're named something like this:

- _email_header.html.erb
- _email_footer.html.erb

Then you can refer to them inside each of your emails:

```
<%= render :partial => 'email_header' %>
Blah, email-specific content here...
<%= render :partial => 'email_footer' %>
```

That will work, but will still lead to a bunch of copy-paste, albeit less than the original version with the full structure inlined. A cleaner way to manage this is to set up a custom layout for these emails.

The ["Layout and Rendering" Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) and the layouts section of the  ["Action Mailer" Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-layouts) are helpful backgrounders for this, if you haven't done this before.

You will see from those references that there are multiple ways to invoke a layout within Action Mailer (and more ways still, outside of a mail context), but to take one example usage, you can create a layout template file here: `app/views/layouts/{your_mailer_name}.html.erb`.  E.g., "user_mailer.html.erb"

Its contents could look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>My Fancy Email</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render :partial => 'email_header' %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render :partial => 'email_footer' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note the `yield` call, that's where your specific email content will render.

This approach keeps your content "[DRY](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Don't_Repeat_Yourself)".

Comment: Do partials essentially insert the code in the spot where you have <%= render.... %>?

Comment: More or less, yes.  More specifically "render" is a Rails function that loads the partial and renders it in that spot. A "partial" is just a fancy name for another template, a fragment that's included in another template. They are denoted in Rails by prepending an underscore to the filename. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: also, I am not really sure how this will all work because I am using action mailer. The .html.erb files are in views/xxx_mailer and I have .rb files in the app/mailers folder. I just don't really get where I would put the layout file above and how I could get the necessary content in using yield. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: Check this out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-layouts

Comment: `footer` and `header` partials could be placed in mailer view folder like so: `app/views/user_mailer/_footer.html.erb` and referenced from the `app/views/layouts/user_mailer.html.erb` template just by `render :partial => 'footer'`.